# 'provided' is obsolete but where is the provided

Tags: java, android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.cobertura'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ch.zhaw.facerecognition"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.5.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

cobertura {
    coverageFormats = [ 'html', 'xml' ]
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.4.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    api 'ch.zhaw:facerecognitionlibrary:1.5.3'
}
```

The compiler is android studio.
Above is my build file after I build it the compiler told me that  Configuration 'provided' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'compileOnly'.
But where is the provided?

Comment: api keyword is exactly the same as the old compile keyword. Thus, if all compile is replaced with api earlier so use compileOnly instead of api should work

Answer (score 0):

Replace "api" with "implementation" and your issue will be solved, like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
implementation 'ch.zhaw:facerecognitionlibrary:1.5.3'
```